# Which of the following subsets are dense in the given spaces?

Tags: general-topology, matrices

1. The sets of trignometric polynomials in thespce of continous functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ which are 2$\pi$ periodic (with the sup norm topology).
2. The subset of $C^{\infty}$ function with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the sup norm topology).
3. $GL(n;\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathbb{M}(n;\mathbb R)$ (with its usual topology after identification with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Comment: Are you required to prove which are dense or simply state it?

Comment: I know 1) and 3) is dense , but how they will prove, please help

Answer (score 0):

1 is dense, because $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$ can be expressed as trigonometric polynomials, and it should be fairly obvious you can approximate any periodic function as a finite sum involving $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,N$. 3 is dense, because if you randomly perturb a singular matrix slightly you get a non-singular matrix (because singular matrices have measure zero because they satisfy a polynomial equation in the entries, namely the determinant is zero). 2 is not dense because if you have a $C^\infty$ function that is unbounded at $\infty$, you will get infinite distance from any $C^\infty$ function that has compact support.